# Trying to cause a deadlock c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

i'm trying to simulate a deadlock in C#. I wrote a simple program but can't obtain the exception. Here the main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WatchesCollection collection = new WatchesCollection();
        Actor actor = new Actor();
        Thread actorThread = new Thread(() => actor.MainTask(collection));
        actorThread.Start();
        while(loop == true)
        {
            string s = Console.ReadLine();
            lock(collection)
            {
                collection.Names.Add(s);
            }
        }

    }
```

With:

```
public class WatchesCollection
{
    public List<string> Names = new List<string>();
}
```

And my second thread "MainTask" method is:

```
   public void MainTask(WatchesCollection collection)
    {
        lock (collection)
        {
            collection.Names.Add("Current");
            while(_stopRequired == true) { }
        }
    }
```

I supposed that if the method locks the "collection" instance forever, the "lock" in the main thread method would trigger the exception - but it doesn't

Comment: Firstly, where is `loop` being set to `true`? Secondly, your `MainTask` loops while `_stopRequired` is *true* - so the name of the variable is opposite to its usage - doesn't make sense.

Comment: Deadlocks does not trigger exceptions. They just deadlock your program stopping any further progress.

Comment: *the exception*... what exception?

Comment: You should try the [no-lock deadlock](http://ericlippert.com/2013/01/31/the-no-lock-deadlock/). Or nested locks, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2543159/122195).

Comment: You shouldn't check the equality for booleans - simply use `while (loop)`.

Comment: You misunderstand what `lock(){}` does. Look up `Monitor.Enter()`